# Zig-Zag, IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, algorithm, cryptography

I have a question. Im try to implement Zig-Zag algorithm ([Rail Fence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rail_fence_cipher)).

[image]

My code looks like below:

```
    int n = 3; 
    int j = 0;
    int charCounter = 0;
    char[,] chars = new char[n, input.Length]; //array to store chars

    while(charCounter <= input.Length) //char counter related to input string
    {
        if (charCounter >= input.Length)
            break;

        chars[nCounter++, j++] = input[charCounter++]; //goes n = 0 => 1 => 2 => 3
        if (nCounter == n)
            for (int i = nCounter; i >= 0; i--) //from this loop, i want to go n => 3 => 2 => 1 => 0 etc
            {
                if (charCounter >= input.Length)
                    break;
                if (nCounter == 0)
                    continue;
                chars[--nCounter, j++] = input[charCounter++];
            } //here i get an exception
    }
```

From sample above i get an `Exception`:

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'

My question is, where i have an error in my code?

when i change line in my nested for loop from this: 
`chars[--nCounter, j++] = input[charCounter++];`

to this: `chars[nCounter--, j++] = input[charCounter++];`

I dont get any exception, but my char array looks like this:

```
char[0,0] = input[0];
char[1,1] = input[1];
char[2,2] = input[2];
char[2,3] = input[3]; //that is wrong, should be [1,3]
char[1,4] = input[4];
//and so on..
```

It should look like this:

```
char[0,0] = input[0];
char[1,1] = input[1];
char[2,2] = input[2];
char[1,3] = input[3]; //here the diffrence
char[0,4] = input[4];
//and so on..
```

Thanks for any advices to improve my code!

**EDIT:**
Based on comments, i make some improvement:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= input.Length; i++)
    chars[i % n, i] = input[i];
```

Iterating by rows works pretty ok, now i need to solve column-thing

Comment: increase a conter with a modulo to loop like 0,1,2,0,1,2.  You don't have to be length n when you can be input lenght /3+1. A string is a Char array you can Simply foreach on it to go throught.

Comment: Could you provide your comment with an answer? Your solution sounds pretty ok. But i think the problem here is to go like this `0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 1 -> 0 -> 1 ->2...`.

Comment: This one is `(n^3 + 2n^2 +1)%4`. For now it's only hint in the right direction. It will need work to became answer. I don't mind someone redacting it.

Comment: And possible aswer should look like `myTextVariable.Select((c,i)=> new {char = c ,  index= [ compute I ] }).GroupBy(x=> x.index)`. And select them back into a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to generate a number sequence increasing from 0 to N decreasing back to 0.
Consider the following :
For N=2 , The sequence is `{0,1,0,1 ..}`
For N=3 , The sequence is `{0,1,2,1,0,1,2 ..}`

We could enumerate those if we had a sequence likethis , with a modulo of N+1<sup>**</sup> :
For N=3 , `{0,1,2,1}`
For N=4 , `{0,1,2,3,2,1}`

To generate this sequence we have to :
Count from 0 to N. 
then Count from N-1 to 0+1. And join both together.

```
static int[] GenerateIncreasingDecreasing(int level)
{
    var tempRange = Enumerable.Range(0, level).ToArray();
    var indexMap = (tempRange.Length < 2) ?
                    tempRange :
                    tempRange.Concat(Enumerable.Range(1, level-2).Reverse());
    return indexMap.ToArray();
}
```

Then the Crypt function will be :

```
static string ZigZag(string input, int level)
{
    var indexMap = GenerateIncreasingDecreasing(level);
    var result =
            input.Select((c, i) => new { 
                    Char = c, 
                    Index = indexMap[i % ((level>2)?(level + 1):level)] 
                })
                .GroupBy(x => x.Index)
                .OrderBy(g => g.Key)
                .SelectMany(x => x.Select(y => y.Char))
                .ToArray();

    return new string(result);
}
```

---

<sup>**</sup> : For  N < 2, there is no repetition. So modulo must be N.

Answer (score 1):

The hardest part is generating the incresing then decreasing part. As there is no  easy mathematical solution to generated  a number sequence increasing from 0 to N then decreasing back to 0.
We will have to 
generate the map manually:

Start at 0, increase till we reach `N-1`, decrease till we 0. Repeat that for every char.

For a TestInput = "abcdef" and level = 3, we have:

```
input    a b c d e f
index    0 1 2 1 0 1
```

Then we group and order those 2 by index :

```
index  inputs
  0     a,e
  1     b,d
  2      c
```

A brunch of `Select` after we have : `{a,e,b,d,c}`. A simple string constructor that accept char array and we have our result string.

```
static string ZigZag(string input, int level)
{
    var indexMap = new List<int>();
    var tempIndex = 0; bool isIncreasing = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
    {
        indexMap.Add(tempIndex);
        if (isIncreasing)
        { // Zig
            tempIndex++;
        }
        else
        {  // Zag
            tempIndex--;
        }

        if (tempIndex == level - 1)
        {
            isIncreasing = false;
        }

        if (tempIndex == 0)
        {
            isIncreasing = true;
        }
    }

    var result =
            input.Select((c, i) => new { Char = c, Index = indexMap[i] })
                .GroupBy(x => x.Index)
                .OrderBy(g => g.Key)
                .SelectMany(x => x.Select(y => y.Char))
                .ToArray();

    return new string(result);
}
```